# Identify String Value is Date or DateTime field in Apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

Working on Salesforce. I have Transaction-1 and Transaction-2 object which has master detailed relationship with the Case Object. Dynamically query is getting created, it's executing on the database and Results coming like below.

This is sample result for Case:

> ({Id=500c000000B1LYCAA3, CaseNumber__c=RPQ-00001231,CreatedById=005c000UUUU, LastModifiedDate=2018-01-02 12:56:03, LastModifiedById=005c000UUUU, OwnerId=005c000UUUU, Category__c=Payment, SubCategory__c=Chase Paymentech, Origin=Email, CreatedDate=2018-01-01 15:22:14, Status=Pending, ContactId=003c000})

All the Date and DateTime fields I need to format based on the logged in users Locale. Mostly dd-MM-yyyy.

```
List<Sobject> s = Database.query(queryStr);
```

s has all above result. How to identify all Date and DateTime fields ? Do I need to iterate over it and used RegEx to identify Date or Date/Time fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like below by taking a reference from link : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm

```
Map<String, Object> finalMap = new Map<String, Object>();
List<Case> mylist = new List<Case>();
Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = myCase.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
for(String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()){
    if(fieldsToValue.get(fieldName) instanceOf Date){
        Date dateValue = Date.valueOf(fieldsToValue.get(fieldName));
        finalMap.put(fieldName, DateTime.newInstance(dateValue.year(), dateValue.month(), dateValue.day()).format());
    }else if(fieldsToValue.get(fieldName) instanceOf DateTime){
        Date dateValue = Date.valueOf(fieldsToValue.get(fieldName));
        finalMap.put(fieldName, DateTime.newInstance(dateValue.year(), dateValue.month(), dateValue.day()).format());
    }else{
        finalMap.put(fieldName, fieldsToValue.get(fieldName));
    }
}
```

How to convert Map finalMap back to SObject?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating that dynamic query? If you're using "describe" calls to learn names of all fields on Case then you're not very far off.

Also remember that just because the query was dynamic it doesn't mean you have to store results in `List<sObject>`. It's perfectly fine to cast it to Cases and then they become so much easier to work with (and if you'll use the results on a VF page, it should handle date formatting for you!). `List<Case> records = Database.query('SELECT Subject FROM Case LIMIT 10');` should be OK.

But, if you really have to, let's try to do it manually. I'll read all fields on Contact (I don't have any date fields on Case in my dev edition) and check how I should format them.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();

Set<String> dateFields = new Set<String>();
Set<String> dateTimeFields = new Set<String>();

List<String> allFields = new List<String>(fieldMap.keyset());
allFields.sort();
System.debug(allFields);

for(String key : fieldMap.keyset()){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe();
    Schema.DisplayType t = dfr.getType();
    if(t == DisplayType.Date){
        dateFields.add(key);
    } else if(t == DisplayType.DateTime){
        dateTimeFields.add(key);
    }
}
System.debug('Date: ' + dateFields);
System.debug('DateTime: ' + dateTimeFields);

String query = String.join(new List<String>{
    'SELECT ' + String.join(allFields, ','),
    'FROM Contact',
    'LIMIT 10'
}, '\n');

List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>) Database.query(query);
for(Contact c : contacts){
    System.debug(c);
    for(String field : dateFields){
        String value = c.get(field) == null ? '(empty)' : ((Date) c.get(field)).format();
        System.debug(field + ': ' + value);
    }
    for(String field : dateTimeFields){
        String value = c.get(field) == null ? '(empty)' : ((DateTime) c.get(field)).format();
        System.debug(field + ': ' + value);
    }
}
```